# Flask error logging file not updating on VPS

Tags: python, logging, flask, digital-ocean, vps

I am following this tutorial on Digitalocean to set up my web application. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

I can run my code on my local machine and get the detailed traceback error messages from the error log, i.e., "flask.log", but this file is not updating on the virtual private server I am using (Ubuntu-16-04).  How can I get Flask's traceback error messages from my VPS?

The python environment I am using is Anaconda. And the following is the code I am using to create the error log file. Debug mode is false.

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('project.settings')

filehandler = logging.FileHandler('flask.log')
filehandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.addHandler(filehandler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the program was killed before the logging file got the chance to update because the system is out of memory. I upgraded the VPS and the issue is resolved.